# Table created by fields from another tables does not show values

Tags: mysql, sql

i have tables post_data and user_record. Which have data inside.

Now I created table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_table` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preview` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `img_url` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rate` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`hash`)
) as select user_record.id, post_data.url, post_data.preview, post_data.img_url, 
post_data.title, post_data.hash, post_data.rate 
from user_record , post_data
```

Gets created successfully,

but when I perform "`select * from post_table`" it shows empty.

why?

post_data value:

```
('123', 'http://ec2-33-226-213-43.compute-1.amazonaws.com/', '\r\n\r\n\r\n \r\n \r\n    \r\n \r\nr\n      \r\n     \r\n    \r\n    \r\n    \r\n  \r\n\r\n    \r\n\r\n\r\n ...', '', 'ThenWat...', '75934958552638f4e45cc39cb0c7ec45', 'undefined'),
('123', 'http://paulgraham.com/', '', '...', '', '...', 'dda473844c159b9f18cbaff136cbd38e', '3'),
('123', 'https://www.facebook.com/', '  me l...', 'https://m-static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/y6/r/Rv99Vzk9qsR.png', '...', 'e203e98e4c606735cf56db84a002fd22', 'undefined'),
('166054635', 'www.facebook.com', '', '...', '', '...', '660328a7f9004d462085aa67a82065db', 'undefined');
('166054635', 'http://stackoverflow.com', ' \r\n...', 'http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png', 'Stack Overflow...', '57f4dad48e7a4f7cd171c654226feb5a', '1.5'),
```

user_record;

```
(123, 'jan', 'mail@mail.com', 'x.jpg'),
(166054635, 'don', 'x@y.com', 'temp.jpg')
```

Comment: Can you post some sample data, tables user_record` and post_data`? Also can show, with some sample data, what you expect as a result?

Comment: Presumably because either post_data or user_record are empty.

Comment: The following example: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a2d4/3), works as expected.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: there is some data, I updated my question with value please see

Comment: @Karimkhan 
try using:
CREATE TABLE post_table AS (YOUR SELECT HERE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a series of guesses.  The first guess is that the table already exists.  If it already exists, then it will not be created again (the `if not exists` part), and it will not be populated.  I would rate this a highly likely.

If this is the case, just do an insert (which is shown below).

Second possibility.  Either `user_record` or `post_data` are empty.  A `cross join` on an empty table produces . . . and empty table.  So you get no data.  I would rate this as rather likely.

A more remote possibility is that the statement is getting split into two, perhaps due to some quirks in the levels of interface.  You would be better off with one of the following, in my opinion:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_table` (
  `id` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `preview` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `img_url` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `rate` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`hash`)
);
insert into post_table(id, url, preview, img_url, title, hash, rate)
    select user_record.id, post_data.url, post_data.preview, post_data.img_url, 
           post_data.title, post_data.hash, post_data.rate 
    from user_record cross join post_data;
```

Alternatively:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post_table` as
    select user_record.id, post_data.url, post_data.preview, post_data.img_url, 
           post_data.title, post_data.hash, post_data.rate 
    from user_record cross join post_data;
```